# Getting Error while tryig to save an aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am new to Lightning Aura component and created a simple component to add 2 numbers. However while saving I am getting this error:

```
Failed to save Add2Numbers_C.cmp: ParseError at [row,col]:[4,50] Message: Element type "aura:attribute" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".: Source
```

below is my component code:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="Number1" type = "Integer" default="39"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Number2" type="Integer"default="2"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sum" type="Integer"/>
    {!v.Number1}+{!v.Number2}={!v.sum}
    <br/><br/>
    <ui:button name="Add" press="{!c.add}"/>
    
</aura:component>
```

below is the code for the js cotroller file:

```
({
add : function(component) {
    var add2=component.get("v.Number1")+component.get("v.Number2");
    component.set("v.sum",add2);
}
```

can some one please help me to understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues in your component.

`<aura:attribute name="Number2" type="Integer"default="2"/>`

no space before `default`.

Second issue is `ui` namespace are being deprecated. [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm&type=5&release=230)

Final Component.

```
<aura:component description="sumComponennt" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="Number1" type = "Integer" default="39"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Number2" type="Integer" default="2"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sum" type="Integer"/>

    <div class="slds-color__background_gray-1">
        {!v.Number1}+{!v.Number2}={!v.sum}
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <lightning:button name="Add" label="Add" onclick="{!c.add}"/>
</aura:component>
```

JS :

```
({
    add: function (component) {
        var add2 = component.get("v.Number1") + component.get("v.Number2");
        component.set("v.sum", add2);
    }
})
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: My previous code worked with the same piece of codes/same codes not sure why it was giving error earlier. However thanks for the answer and I will later on check the solution provided by you as well.